# Trying to scrape authenticity token from within a meta tag using requests and beautiful soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to get the value of 'content' from:

```
<meta content="trjYXw9aFup1tXoiuKixHZwcRLBEXeKOH6tqN7VuzvL7cSti/RuS4w06osJ46PwIp3Q+swKbcNeeqqhm7I7cig==" name="csrf-token"/>
```

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with requests.Session() as c:
    url = 'https://www.teamtreehouse.com/'
    r=requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
    csrfToken = soup.find('meta', attrs={'name': 'csrf-token'})
    authenticity_token = csrfToken.findAll('content')
```

when i `print(csrfToken)` i get `<meta content="trjYXw9aFup1tXoiuKixHZwcRLBEXeKOH6tqN7VuzvL7cSti/RuS4w06osJ46PwIp3Q+swKbcNeeqqhm7I7cig==" name="csrf-token"/>`

Now when i try and `print(authenticity_token)` i get `[]`

i am trying to get value of content on its own, can anyone advise please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `get()` method to get the value of attribute `content`.
You are using [find_all()](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all), which get all the occurences of a tag inside the soup element you are running the method.

Like this:

```
authenticity_token = csrfToken.get('content');
```

so the result of

```
print(authenticity_token)
```

will be

```
trjYXw9aFup1tXoiuKixHZwcRLBEXeKOH6tqN7VuzvL7cSti/RuS4w06osJ46PwIp3Q+swKbcNeeqqhm7I7cig==
```